# Efficient C pool allocator?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, memory-management

I'm currently attempting to write a 2D scene graph in C, and I need to decide on a way of storing the child nodes. I'm expecting very many reads and few writes, so a linked list is out of the question due to poor spatial locality of reference, and using `realloc` every time to add a child node would probably fragment the free list into oblivion. A pool allocator seems to be the best solution, but I can't seem to find any implementations to use. Does anyone know of an allocator that would efficiently handle random-ish allocations and deallocations of a few hundred small `struct`s, or perhaps a better allocation scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm preparing to deploy [TLSF](http://www.gii.upv.es/tlsf/) as a real-time allocator. I haven't had a chance to profile its performance yet, but it seems to work, and the [license](http://www.gii.upv.es/tlsf/main/license) is right.

According to their docs, its operations execute "a maximum of 168 processor instructions in a x86 architecture". It comes as a single .c file, which compiled without modifications on my system.

Comment: @CAFxX - Shame. Google finds me some alternate sites, but none seem to be official. Hopefully that will change.

Comment: Yay! Thanks for the fix, @Electro . Giving you a semi-random upvote. Chalk another win for crowd-sourced knowledge.

Comment: @T.E.D. Well, I do like to go over my own questions once in a while - can't have links rotting away :P

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In my informal benchmark, it beats glibc's `malloc` by 25% or more. But it is slightly slower for `free`. Unfortunately, it segfaults when you try to make a memory pool 2gb or larger in size.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist - ...which immediately tells me - signed 32-bit integer being used somewhere. Hopefully its fixable. 32-bit systems are essentially obsolete now, except for specialized uses.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at halloc, it might be of some help.

http://swapped.cc/halloc/

Comment: `halloc` looks interesting, but it still works on top of `malloc`, so the fragmentation issue remains, though I guess it might prove useful as a starting point for a pool allocator.